# Can couples takes the shower together?

Tags: sex

My husband loves me alot. When every I take the shower and my husband at home. He take shower with me. During shower, we always did sex. Is it right or wrong?

Comment: It's fine. You just have to do proper ghusl afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowhere in Quran or Hadith is it mentioned that couples cannot have a shower together.

Infact the prophet pbuh used to do the same.

> Sahih Al-Bukhari Hadith 1.272 Narrated by Hisham bin Urwa
>
> Aisha said, "I and Allah's
> Messenger (saws) used to take a bath from a single water container,
> from which we took water simultaneously."

In another hadith:

> Sahih Al-Bukhari Hadith 1.261 Narrated by Aisha
>
> The Prophet (saws) and I used to take a bath from a single pot of
> water and our hands used to go in the pot after each other in turn.

Now the question remains about whether having sex during shower... Again, nowhere is it mentioned in both Quran or Hadith that you shall not have sex during shower.

However, as always the rules for doing sex as usual applies, which are as follows:

1. Sexual intercource must be between a male and a female.
2. The female should either be a wife or a concubine of the male.
3. The female should not have sex during periods.
4. In some hadiths sex in the anus is prohibited.
5. One should not have sex while fasting. Sex while fasting is not haram, but it breaks the fast.

Comment: Anal sex is completely haraam. There is consensus of ummah and this is mentioned in ahadith. The way Qaisar Khan presents Point number 4 is tricky. Tries to make you believe that there is some scope for anal sex.  Point number 5 is wrong, breaking fast is sin and anything which breaks fast is haraam. So sex is haraam during the fast (daytime) because it breaks the fast. Infact, one of the aims of fasting is to have control from the lust. Walahuaalam

Answer (score -5):

Yes it is perfectly fine and permissible